# Microservice Setup

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, microservices

I have a several git repo that I want to manage via docker-compose. I also want the project where the docker-compose resides to be a git repo. So I have the following organization:

`UI-Repo
  --> .git
  --> Dockerfile`

`Server-Repo
  --> .git
  --> Dockerfile`

`Local-Development-Repo
  --> .git
  --> docker-compose.yml`

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to access the UI-Repo and Server-Repo dockerfiles due to limitations in Docker. Having a sym link for the UI-Repo and Server-Repo inside the Local-Development-Repo does not work either. So I can think of two options.

1. Git Submodules

   - The downside to this approach is that I will need to copy package.json and perform a `npm install` inside my dockerfiles since `node_modules` is on my .gitignore. I want this purely for development and ideally, should just use volumes instead of installing dependencies inside the docker container.
2. House UI-Repo and Server-Repo inside a parent directory, which contains the docker-compose.yml file.

   - The downside to this approach is that I want this parent to be tracked via Git as well. I do not think having .git in the parent directory that houses two more git repo will work.

What is the suggested practice to set up microservices architecture having several independent git repos and manage these projects for local development using docker-compose?

Comment: If you wish to reference other repositories in your docker-compose, why do you need access to their Dockerfile? You create the image of other docker images on their own repo, and in your docker-compose, you just reference them. Am I missing your use-case maybe?

Comment: @Rash - I am thinking that docker-compose is used to better manage a lot of different services in your project so that you can simply execute `docker-compose up` to run both server and UI services (without the need to build and run each repo everytime). I want to take advantage of the "volume" inside the docker-compose for each project. That way, if I change something on the UI perhaps during development, the running service can automatically detect it (without the need to rebuild and rerun the image).

Comment: So you simply need a base dockerfile for all your UI projects, where the actual files would be loaded via the volume option. Build those dockerfile separately, and in your docker-compose reference those builds, and mount data to those builds. You don't need access to the dockerfiles of those other projects.

Comment: did you problem got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like:

`Parent-Folder
- docker-compose.yml (sym linked to Local-Development-Repo/docker-compose.yml)
- Local-Development-Repo
  - docker-compose.yml
- UI-Repo
- Server-Repo`

This way, I can track docker-compose.yml and at the same time can start all the services via `docker-compose-up` from the Parent-Folder.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need access to `Dockerfile` of your other UI projects.
For all your UI projects, build their image locally in their own project.
Then reference those images to your docker-compose file like below.

While referencing, you can mount the respective codebase inside your docker.
This way, even if you change your UI code, you never have to rebuild your docker image again.

```
version: "2"
services:
  UIProjectA:
    image: ui_project_A_local_build:0.0.1
    container_name: ui_project_A_local_build
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/local/folder/in/project/A:/path/to/docker/folder
  UIProjectB:
    image: ui_project_B_local_build:0.0.1
    container_name: ui_project_B_local_build
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/local/folder/in/project/B:/path/to/docker/folder
```

Comment: A negative vote without any comments are bad manners. If there are issues with answers, please discuss. I tested my setup and it works, so I am positive I answered the question correctly.

Comment: I do not know who downvoted your answer (and for @lecstor below) but yours worked though I ended up doing it differently since I do not want to build each repo manually. I ended up something like:

Parent
  - docker-compose.yml (sym linked to Local-Development-Repo/docker-compose.yml)
 - Local-Development-Repo
     --> docker-compose.yml
 - UI-Repo
 - Server-Repo

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Sorry chris. My comment was not for you. I hope you were not offended. Regarding my answer, you don't have to build your project again and again. You simply build the UIProjectA and UIProjectB once with empty apache2 containers, and your docker-compose will mount the actual code before starting your containers.
The downside in your approach could be that any other project wanting to use the same Dockerfiles would have to rebuild that project anyhow. So why not do it one time for every project. Let me know if I need to elaborate more. I can write specific commands to make things clear.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the issue is only with your docker-compose file. I have the same directory structure and it works fine. You just need to set the build context as the repo directory and run docker-compose from within Local-Development-Repo.

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  ui:
    image: ui
    container_name: ui
    build:
      context: ../UI-Repo
  server:
    build:
      context: ../Server-Repo
    image: server
    container_name: server
```

Comment: I think this works for you because you specified an image, which is already built.

Comment: nope, if the image doesn't exist, when you do `docker-compose up ui` it will be built/created. If it does exist and you want to build again you can just `docker-compose build ui`. (and if you just `docker-compose up` it will build/start all services as necessary)